# jQuery Validate .addMethod on attribute based validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to make data attributes based validation.
However, when I'm adding my `numeric` method, it's not working.

```
    $.validator.addMethod('[data-v-numeric="numeric"]', function(value, element) {
        console.log(1);
        return !isNaN(parseInt(value));
    }, objLanguage['validation_numeric']);
```

What I found in the documentation:
"name
Type: String
The name of the method used to identify it and referencing it; this must be a valid JavaScript identifier"

So I have 2 elements `$('[data-v-numeric="numeric"]')` and how I thought `[data-v-numeric="numeric"]` is valid JavaScript selector. But somehow It's not working. Where I made an error then?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4bwy2tL9/1/

Comment: You should really study the documentation for the `addMethod` method.  http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/

Answer (score 3):

You are using the `jQuery.validator.addMethod` incorrectly. Please see the documentation http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/

```
var errorMessages = {
    'validation_integer': "Must be integer input.",
    'validation_positive': "Must be positive integer input.",
    // ...
};
$.validator.addMethod('integer', function(value, element) {
        return !isNaN(parseInt(value));
}, errorMessages['validation_integer']);
$.validator.addMethod('positive', function(value, element) {
        return !isNaN(parseInt(value)) && parseInt(value) >= 0;
}, errorMessages['validation_positive']);
// ...
```

Comment: I need exactly `[data-v-numeric="numeric"]` because I want to have also `[data-v-numeric="integer"]`, `[data-v-numeric="positive"]`, `[data-v-numeric="decimal"]` etc.

Comment: I updated my answer, you are using the method incorrectly.